# Log4j2 Arguments given for element Logger are invalid

Tags: java, logging, log4j2, weblogic-10.x

I am facing below error on upgradation of log4j 1.x to log4j2.
As per documentation on log4j2 site I have prepared below log4j2 file, but still I am getting this exception.

Log4j2 version: 2.6.1, Weblogic: 10.3.6, jdk 1.7.x

Please help with this exception:

```
2016-06-25 05:49:36,002 [ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '70' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)' ERROR Unable to invoke factory method in class class org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggerConfig for element Logger. org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.ConfigurationException: Arguments given for element Logger are invalid
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.plugins.util.PluginBuilder.generateParameters(PluginBuilder.java:270)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.plugins.util.PluginBuilder.build(PluginBuilder.java:131)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.createPluginObject(AbstractConfiguration.java:918)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.createConfiguration(AbstractConfiguration.java:858)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.createConfiguration(AbstractConfiguration.java:850)
```

Log4j2.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="DEBUG" >
      <Properties>
        <Property name="theHostName">${hostName}</Property>
      </Properties>
      <!-- bufferedIO=true by default, bufferSize=8192bytes 
      -->
      <Appenders>
            <RollingFile name="FILE" filename="${sys:weblogic.Name}.log" filepattern="${sys:weblogic.Name}.log.%i" append="true" >
                <PatternLayout pattern="[%-5p][%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS}][${sys:weblogic.Name}:${hostName}][%t][%X{MessageInfo}][%c{1}:%M:%L][%msg]%n" />
                <Policies>
                    <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="50 MB" />
                </Policies>
                <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="100" fileIndex="min"/>
            </RollingFile>
      </Appenders>
      <Loggers>
            <Logger level="DEBUG" includeLocation="true">
              <AppenderRef ref="FILE"/>
            </Logger>
            <Root level="INFO" includeLocation="true">
              <AppenderRef ref="FILE"/>
            </Root>
            <!--  Package specific log level defines -->
            <logger level="WARN" name="org.springframework" />
            <logger level="WARN" name="org.jboss" />
            <logger level="OFF" name="org.hibernate" />
            <logger level="WARN" name="com.company.project.eligibility" />
      </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess package specific levels should be commented out or declared like this:

```
<Logger level="WARN" name="org.springframework" />
<Logger level="WARN" name="org.jboss" />
<Logger level="OFF" name="org.hibernate" />
<Logger level="WARN" name="com.company.project.eligibility" />
```

Comment: Log4j configuration is not case-sensitive so there is no difference between this answer and the configuration in the question... I don't see how this can be the correct answer.

Answer (score 3):

Only the root logger can have no name, so this Logger needs to have a name:

```
<Logger level="DEBUG" includeLocation="true">
   <AppenderRef ref="FILE"/>
</Logger>
```

Comment: If I will add name="com.company" it prints duplicate logs in file for every line.

Comment: Then add `additivity="false"` to that logger config.

Comment: Thanks I will try this option.